# Date is getting merged in time format

Tags: java, plsql, oracle12c

when i am inserting data in a table having datatype TIMESTAMP. date is getting merged in Time format, This problem occurs when i am inserting date below year 2013 or 2011.
i have tried changing NLS formats as well but i did not work.

Is there any alternative of timestamp in oracle.
However i am able to insert using to_date and getting satisfactory output but i have to insert '21-feb-2011' and need output '21-02-11 00:00:00.000000000 AM    21-02-11'

```
create table date_with_time (Timestamp_ex TIMESTAMP , Date_ex Date);

insert into date_with_time values('21-feb-2011','21-feb-2011');

select * from date_with_time;
```

Result:

```
Timestamp_ex 
21-02-20 11:00:00.000000000 AM      

Date_ex 
21-02-11
```

Actual Result:
Result:

```
Timestamp_ex                    
21-02-20 11:00:00.000000000 AM  

Date_ex 
21-02-11
```

Expected Result:

```
Timestamp_ex

21-02-11 00:00:00.000000000 AM     

Date_ex  

21-02-11
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the presentation layer that bothers you, I think. If you want to format those values, use `TO_CHAR` and appropriate format mask. For example:

```
SQL> create table test (ts_ex timestamp, dt_ex date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (systimestamp, sysdate);

1 row created.
```

This is what default NLS settings return:

```
SQL> select * from test;

TS_EX                          DT_EX
------------------------------ ----------
11.10.19 12:50:05,468126       11.10.2019
```

If you want different format, say so:

```
SQL> select to_char(ts_ex, 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi:ss:ff am') tx,
  2         to_char(dt_ex, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dx
  3  from test;

TX                             DX
------------------------------ -------------------
11-10-19 12:50:05:468126 PM    11.10.2019 12:50:05

SQL>
```

---

As of **2012**: it doesn't matter, really. Once again: it is presentation you want, not the way data is stored into the table (in Oracle's internal format).

```
SQL> insert into test (ts_ex, dt_ex) values
  2    (to_timestamp('21.02.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
  3     to_date     ('21.02.2011', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yy';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd-mm-yy hh:mi:ss:ff am';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

TS_EX                          DT_EX
------------------------------ --------
21-02-11 12:00:00:000000 AM    21-02-11

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: running code from your comment]**

```
SQL> create table date_with_time (Timestamp_ex TIMESTAMP , Date_ex Date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into date_with_time values('21-feb-2019','21-feb-2019');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from date_with_time;

TIMESTAMP_EX                   DATE_EX
------------------------------ --------
21.02.20 19:00:00,000000       21.02.19
      ^^^^^
      this is 2019, year
```

As I told you: don't rely on implicit conversion, have control over the process, use appropriate functions with appropriate format masks.

Comment: i want to insert date below year 2012 . i have tried to_char as well but i need output without using to_char . e.g  select * from date_with_time;

Comment: Year is not a problem (I added some more code; have a look). Once again: it is about **presentation**, not data itself.

Comment: @ShreeNaikawadi _i need output without using to_char_ Why?

Comment: Is it necessary to add to_timestamp or To_date while inserting data.  Because the problem is with year when i am inserting date above 2014 or more eg. 2018 or 2019. it is showing me proper result. so what the problem with 2011 or 2012.  try using this insert into date_with_time values('21-feb-2019','21-feb-2019');

select * from date_with_time;

Comment: The way you do it, you are inserting **strings** (values enclosed into single quotes) and **hope** that Oracle will properly interpret those strings and implicitly convert them to desired datatypes. From my point of view, yes - it is necessary to take control over it and use appropriate functions and data formats.

Comment: Thanks @Abra .  because i am getting satisfactory output without using to_char and that to for year 2019.  so why would i need that special function for year 2011. Please check this out . insert into date_with_time values('21-feb-2019','21-feb-2019');

select * from date_with_time;

Comment: @ Littlefoot Thanks. I understood that. but why we need special treatment for 2011 or 2012 because i am getting satisfactory output when i am inserting year 2019 instead of 2011 that too with select * from date_with_time;

Comment: @Littlefoot Please try this.        create table date_with_time (Timestamp_ex TIMESTAMP , Date_ex Date);

insert into date_with_time values('21-feb-2019','21-feb-2019');

select * from date_with_time;

Comment: I have; see the [ EDIT ] part in my answer. I kind of feel tired of repeating it over and over again ... don't rely on implicit conversion, use appropriate functions and format masks.